# e-commerce app generate pdf invoice using Node.js and MySQL Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, e-commerce, invoice

I am creating a Dummy E-commerce app using Express JS.
I have created functionality to order and Dummy payment. If order is placed successfully, I want to create a pdf invoice of order and store in MySQL database using Sequelize. which can be sent to user's email address or downloaded by user by request.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I am searching stuff. Since, I have no idea about it. Have found one node.js library PDFKit.
 Which does not support Complex formatting of text (in Table form)

Answer (score 0):

One way to generate pdfs with complex formatting in node.js is https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-node

You can use html to generate a table with complex formatting and this library will generate a pdf you can store on disk or object store.

```
var html_to_pdf = require('html-pdf-node');
let options = { format: 'A4' };

// request handler
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  let file = { content: "<table><tbody><tr><td>Welcome to html-pdf-node</td></tr></tbody>/table>" };
  html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options).then(pdfBuffer => {
    console.log("PDF Buffer:-", pdfBuffer);
    // save pdfBuffer to disk or object store and save url in database record
  });
});
```